# Duplicate hash into independent hash (shallow copy)

Tags: ruby

What is the best way to duplicate a hash in Ruby, and have it independent from the original? For example:

```
a = { foo1: "bar1" }
b = a # or b = a.clone / b = a.dup for that matter
b[:foo2] = "bar2"
```

This results in:

```
{:foo1=>"bar1", :foo2=>"bar2"} # a
{:foo1=>"bar1", :foo2=>"bar2"} # b
```

Where I would like it to be

```
{:foo1=>"bar1"}                # a
{:foo1=>"bar1", :foo2=>"bar2"} # b
```

Now I know about `b = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(a))` but that seems like a little overkill, and I was wondering if there is a better way, because I can't really find it.

Comment: It works for me with `dup`...

Comment: What? Now it does for me too. I've tried everything and nothing seemed to work... What is this sorcery! :( Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could write

```
a = { k: 'dog' }
b = {}.merge(a)
  #=> {:k=>"dog"}
b[:cat] = 'meow'

a #=> {:k=>"dog"}
b #=> {:k=>"dog", :cat=>"meow"}
```

but we wary of

```
a = { k: [:cow, :pig] }
b = {}.merge(a)
  #=> {:k=>[:cow, :pig]}
b[:k] << 'chicken'
  #=> [:cow, :pig, "chicken"]

a #=> {:k=>[:cow, :pig, "chicken"]}
b #=> {:k=>[:cow, :pig, "chicken"]}
```

`a` is not what we want.

One way to ensure you create a *deep copy* of the hash is to use [Marshal#dump](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) and [Marshal#load](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Marshal.html#method-c-load):

```
a = { :k=>[1, [2, [3, { :m=>[4] }]]] }
b = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(a))
  #=> {:k=>[1, [2, [3, {:m=>[4]}]]]}

b[:k][-1][-1][-1][:m] << 5

a #=> {:k=>[1, [2, [3, {:m=>[4]}]]]}
b #=> {:k=>[1, [2, [3, {:m=>[4, 5]}]]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Kernel#dup`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-dup) and [`Kernel#clone`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-clone) do just what you want :

```
a = {foo1: "bar1"}
b = a.dup # or a.clone

b[:foo2] = "bar2"

p b
# {:foo1=>"bar1", :foo2=>"bar2"}
p a
# {:foo1=>"bar1"}
```

As you requested, it's a shallow copy, though:

```
a = {foo1: ["bar1"]}
b = a.clone

b[:foo1] << 'bar2'
b[:foo3] = 'bar3'

p a
# {:foo1=>["bar1", "bar2"]}
p b
# {:foo1=>["bar1", "bar2"], :foo3=>"bar3"}
```